# rvm get latest is throwing error

Tags: ruby, osx-snow-leopard, rvm

Trying to upgrade RVM on my OSx. I am getting the below error.

```
$ rvm get latest

Original installed RVM version:

rvm 1.2.9 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

rvm-<html>
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   172    0   172    0     0    210      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   304
ERROR:
.tar.gz downloaded does not match it's md5 checksum <html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.0.8</center>
</body>
./html>
Aborting RVM Installation.
```

What could be wrong ?

Comment: Looking at this solution by wayneeseguin [here](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager/browse_thread/thread/fad471eb4c27dd38)

Comment: Trying `rvm get head` solved the problem w00t !!

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
rvm get head
rvm reload
rvm get stable
```

in case `rvm get head fails use installer instead:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm reload
```

The `rvm reload` is important, it was required earlier but now RVM will autoreload itself.

Also note that around `1.4` RVM changed `.rvmrc` trusting mechanism and you will have to trust all your projects again ... or use the new project files which do not require trusting: https://rvm.io/workflow/projects/#ruby-versions